# json decoding in php and insert into mysql DB

Tags: php, mysql, json

this is my json data, i am try to decode this json and store  the data in mysql database.
i am try  json decoding in php. In my php server side  json  data are not decoded and not stored in mysql database. please help me to solve this problem.

**JSON DATA**

```
{  
   "code":"0",
   "message":"Success",
   "events":[  
      {  
         "id":1,
         "name":"test event",
         "description":"test desc",
         "date":"2014-06-22 00:00:00",
         "location":"keelapalur",
         "type":1,
         "passcode":"123456",
         "created":{  
            "date":"2014-06-08 17:05:12",
            "timezone_type":3,
            "timezone":"UTC"
         },
         "updated":{  
            "date":"2014-06-08 17:05:12",
            "timezone_type":3,
            "timezone":"UTC"
         }
      },
      {  
         "id":2,
         "name":"rtyr",
         "description":"rtyr",
         "date":"2014-06-22 00:00:00",
         "location":"try",
         "type":1,
         "passcode":"123456",
         "created":{  
            "date":"2014-06-12 09:26:31",
            "timezone_type":3,
            "timezone":"UTC"
         },
         "updated":{  
            "date":"2014-06-12 09:26:31",
            "timezone_type":3,
            "timezone":"UTC"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

**PHP code**

```
<?php 
$response = array();
$res=array();
    require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';
    $json = file_get_contents('/insert.json');
    if($json!=null){
    $decoded=json_decode($json,true);
    //$decode= var_dump($decoded);
    //$ss=$decode["array"];
    //echo $decoded['number'];
    if(sizeof($decoded["events"])>0)
    {
    for($i=0;$i>sizeof($decoded["events"]);$i++)
    {
    $id=$decoded["events"]["id"];
$name=$decoded["events"]["name"];
$date=$decoded["events"]["date"];
$desc=$decoded["events"]["description"];
$location=$decoded["events"]["location"];
$type=$decoded["events"]["type"];
$passcode=$decoded["events"]["passcode"];
$cdate=$decoded["events"]["created"]["date"];
$ctimzonety=    $decoded["events"]["created"]["timezone_type"];
$ctimz=$decoded["events"]["created"]["timezone"];
$udate=$decoded["events"]["updated"]["date"];
$utimzonety=    $decoded["events"]["updated"]["timezone_type"];
$utimz=$decoded["events"]["updated"]["timezone"];

$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO events(userid,name,desc,date,loc,type,passcode,cdate,ctimezone_type,ctimezone,udate,utimezone_type,utimezone) 
VALUES('$id,'$name','$desc','$date','$loc','$type','$passcode','$cdate','$ctimzonety','$ctimz','$udate','$utimzonety','$utimz')");

    // check if row inserted or not
    if ($result) {
        // successfully inserted into database
        $response["code"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "successfully stored";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // failed to insert row
        $response["code"] = 2;
        $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    }



}
    }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Transform it to an object and then iterate over it to insert in the database the data in the correct place. I don't know PHP but it shouldn't be very difficult.

Comment: so what's the problem? what's (not) happening?

Comment: my json decoding code is wrong ,its main problem for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make ensure your database connectivity..Try this code 100% it's working...

```
<?php 
$response = array();
$res=array();

    $json = file_get_contents('C:\Users\Devunne3\Desktop\insert.json');

    if($json!=null){
    $decoded=json_decode($json,true);
    //$decode= var_dump($decoded);
    //$ss=$decode["array"];
    //echo $decoded['number'];
    if(is_array($decoded["events"]))
    {
    foreach($decoded["events"] as $events)
    //for($i=0;$i>sizeof($decoded["events"]);$i++)

    {
    $id=$events["id"];
    echo "<br />","userid:",$id,"<br />";

$name=$events["name"];
echo "name:",$name,"<br />";
$date=$events["date"];
echo "date:",$date,"<br />";
$desc=$events["description"];
echo "desc:",$desc,"<br />";
$location=$events["location"];
echo "loc:",$location,"<br />";
$type=$events["type"];
echo "type:",$type,"<br />";
$passcode=$events["passcode"];
echo "passcode:",$passcode,"<br />";
$cdate=$events["created"]["date"];
echo "cdate:",$cdate,"<br />";
$ctimzonety=$events["created"]["timezone_type"];
echo "ctimezone_type:",$ctimzonety,"<br />";
$ctimz=$events["created"]["timezone"];
echo "ctimezone:",$ctimz,"<br />";
$udate=$events["updated"]["date"];
echo "udate:",$udate,"<br />";
$utimzonety=$events["updated"]["timezone_type"];
echo "utimezone_type:",$utimzonety,"<br />";
$utimz=$events["updated"]["timezone"];
echo "utimezone",$utimz,"<br />";
echo"------------------------------------------------","<br />";

require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';
 $db = new DB_CONNECT();

$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO events(userid,name,desc,date,loc,type,passcode,cdate,ctimezone_type,ctimezone,udate,utimezone_type,utimezone)
VALUES('$id','$name','$desc','$date','$location','$type','$passcode','$cdate','$ctimzonety','$ctimz','$udate','$utimzonety','$utimz')")or die("Insert Failed ".mysql_error());;

    }// check if row inserted or not
    if ($result) {
        // successfully inserted into database
        $response["code"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "successfully stored";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // failed to insert row
        $response["code"] = 2;
        $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    }

    }
    }



?>
```